# How to hide characters of a name by X?

Tags: php

I want to display only first three and last three characters of a name. Other characters should be hidden by X.
For example,

```
$name = "ELVIS MASTAINE KANGABAM";
```

I want to echo the above name like the following:

```
$hidden_name = "ELVXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXBAM";  

echo $hidden_name;
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: What should happen if the name is `Jon Doe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use preg_replace on all a-Z chars from substr 3 -> -3 and replace them with X.

```
$name = "ELVIS MASTAINE KANGABAM";  
$hidden_name = substr($name, 0,3) . preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z])/", "x", substr($name,3,-3)) . substr($name, -3); 
echo $hidden_name;
```

https://3v4l.org/CEK9B

Comment: Doesn't work with umlauts, when the name contains dashes, accents, etc.

Comment: @localheinz do you see the post above from OP? If OP says it works for his needs, seriously?? Also his question did not include what should be done with dashes, but it does not mask them and that is in my opinion correct since that makes the names readable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use substr and concatenation eg:

```
$hidden_name = substr($name ,0, 3). str_repeat("x", strlen($name)-6) . substr($name , -3);
echo $hidden_name;
```

Comment: Does not match OPs expected result

Comment: i think that should return ELVXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXBAM

Comment: https://3v4l.org/dkWTv when you have corrected the missing `,` and the lenght() to strlen it returns => https://3v4l.org/q6HgG spaces are `x`